# Azure Batch Services: TaskStateMonitor on Intentional Task Deletion

Tags: c#, azure, azure-batch

In Azure batch services, when a task is added to a job, you are able to create a TaskStateMonitor which will wait for the completion/timeout of the added task. When a task completes (or timeouts), the monitor will return (or raise an exception).

What happens to the monitor if you delete the job before completion? Does the task monitor wait until the timeout is reached, does it raise a different exception, or does it consider the job as being completed?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: After testing this on my end, The TaskStateMonitor will raise the following exception when it checks for a state and cannot find one

`Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Common.BatchException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'`